# Enable-PSRemoting (Set-WSManQuickConfig) and HyperV adapter

Tags: hyper-v, powershell-remoting

After installing HyperV and appearing 
*vEthernet (default switch) Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter*
command
*Enable-PSRemoting (or Set-WSManQuickConfig)*
throws an exception:

```
 et-WSManQuickConfig : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859113" Machine="localhost"><f:Message><f:ProviderFault provider="Config provider" path="%systemroot%\system32
\WsmSvc.dll"><f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859113" Machine="*******"><f:Message>WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection types
 on this machine is set to Public. Change the network connection type to either Domain or Private and try again. </f:Message></f:WSManFault></f:ProviderFault></f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-WSManQuickConfig
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

Disabling the virtual switch brings properly command work.
Why it occurs and may it be resolved?
OS: Windows 10; PSVersion - 5.1.18362.145

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft considers powershell remoting harmful if network connection types "public" are found on the system. Those are created by Hyper-V as default virtual network switch. You can skip this check with a commandline parameter.

```
Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck
```